# Проблема при билде на ios игры с Unity

Tags: ios, unity3d, xcode

[image: проблема в xcode]

Долго не могу решить эту проблему. 
Собирал игру в  Unity  на маке.  Сбилдилось без ошибок
уже в xcode   через соответствующее меню добавил недостающий  CoreData.fraemwork (из-за этого тоже раньше выдавало ошибку)
Именно в юнити есть скрипт в папкеAssets/Plugins  с подобным названием OpenUDID. Где то на просторах интернета нашел инфу что его нужно переместить из папки плагинов куда то в другое место. но это не принесло для меня результатов . 
Проект запускаю через xcworkspace , а не через .xcodeproj
Scripting BeckEnd l2cpp.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_GetOpenUDID", referenced from:
      _OpenUDIDPlugin_GetOpenUDID_m415576254 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
     (maybe you meant: _OpenUDIDPlugin_GetOpenUDID_m415576254)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Почему нельзя просто *скопировать* код ошибки? Зачем нужно обязательно делать скриншот?

Answer (score 1):

проверьте пожалуйста в настройках вашего проекта: Build and settings->Player Settings;
Там будет поле в инспекторе Signing Team ID , убедитесь что вы его заполнили.
Прикреплю миниатюру, надеюсь хоть как-то поможет.(Зелёным выделено нужное вам поле)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там нужно именно название компании написать?

Comment: нет, не совсем Signing Team ID , это ваш  ID на сайте разработчика (логин если быть точным):https://developer.apple.com/

Comment: Спасибо, я завтра попробую это проделать. А то такого я не прописывал.

Comment: Думаю, это поможет я когда впервые "билдил" видел подобные ошибки, ибо для "билда" под Apple нужно верифицироваться как разработчик, (думаю из целей безопасности). Думаю после заполнения необходимых полей все выйдет.

Comment: Эта ошибка больше не появляется нo xcode  просто висит и не заканчивает компиляцию

Comment: Тогда проверьте (можно по гайду в инете, вот вроде неплохой: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fM9E6b0LNQI ) Просто еще может быть ошибка заполнения других параметров потому и кинул ссылку, ибо обычно если Юнити не ругается а xcod не компилит, то что-то не так настроено.

Comment: Спасибо, я сегодня это попробую.

Comment: вроде с параметрами все хорошо. Но проблема остается. Не могу понять причину. Странно все это

Comment: А что за ошибки у вас возникают и на каком этапе ? в самом Unity  или уже в компиляции в Xcode?

Comment: Уже при билде в хкоде. И даже не ошибка. Билд просто зависает. Компиляться файлы. Перед этапом линкования. И билд так и висит.

Comment: Долго с этим мучаюсь и Уде и не знаю что можно сделать. Все ваши варианты пробовал.

Comment: Тогда склоняюсь к тому, что что-то не так в самом коде что выдает юнити.. может ошибка есть или предупреждение, что-то должно быть. Хотя нужно посмотреть может это еще и сам XCode. Ну вернее проблема в его настройке, к сожалению у меня сейчас нет под рукой машини с мак ос... И тут остается только гуглить, ибо варианта только 2 или ошибка в юнити ( в самом коде)(но если ни на что не ругается то это маловероятно) Либо это проблема уже в самом XCode, возможно настройки какие то не так установлены.Если бы вы могли получить код ошибки то это все бы упростило.

Comment: Там вылазит около 600 варнингов. Я об хкоде. Но так было и раньше, когда оно билдилось.

Comment: Но спасибо вам за все те советы.

Comment: Возможно, стоит задать новый вопрос, только уже под другими тегами и приложить материалы, возможно вам помогут )

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваши ответы.